# how to limit zoom on a map in react native with <MapView/> component

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

```
<Map

          ref={mapRef}
          key={mapShouldUpdate}
          showsUserLocation
          userLocationAnnotationTitle={`Ma position`}
          showsMyLocationButton
          showsPointsOfInterest={false}
          showsBuildings={false}
          showsTraffic={false}
          showsIndoors={false}
          minZoomLevel={9}
          maxZoomLevel={12}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          pitchEnabled={false}
          toolbarEnabled={false}
          loadingEnabled={usersLoading || offersLoading}
          moveOnMarkerPress={false}
          mapType={getMapType()}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: mapCenter?.latitude,
            longitude: mapCenter?.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4,
            longitudeDelta: 0.2,
          }}
          onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => {
            setMapCenter(region)
            onRegionChangeComplete?.(region)
          }}
          style={{ ...eva.style.Map, ...style }}
        >
```

I tried changing the **minZoomLevel**, **maxZoomLevel**, **latitudeDelta**, **longitudeDelta**  but it doesn't render what I want. I would like the user zoom to be limited.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
minDelta={0.05}
maxDelta={2}
```

it should work!